# index and length must refer to a location within the string vb

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have to import an Excel file into an Access db. My Excel has a column called 'Description'. Usually the description is long a cell, but it can happens that is more long. If it is long more than 255 characters, I cut the string and I modify last 3 characters with '...'.
When I run the program, though, I have an error "Index and length must refer to a location within the string".
I tried even to erase the check on the length, but obviously I had this error "Field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add"

```
If flag = 2 Then
                stringVoice = grid(r, 3).Text
                voc.Description = voc.Description & stringVoice
                If voc.Description.Length > 255 Then
                    voc.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString.Substring(0, 252) + "..."
                End If
End If
```

This is the code that produced the Index and length error. Same check has done before if inside a single cell there are more than 255 characters

```
Case 1 'voce
                    id = id + 1
                    flag = 2

                    voc = New cVoce
                    c_Voc = voc.Cod_Chapter
                    p_Voc = voc.Cod_Paragraph
                    voc.Cod_Chapter = grid(r, 1).Text.Substring(0, 1)
                    voc.Cod_Paragraph = grid(r, 1).Text.Split(".")(0)
                    voc.Cod_Voice = Right(vett(0), 2)
                    If grid(r, 3).Text.Length > 255 Then
                        voc.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString.Substring(0, 252) + "..."
                    Else
                        voc.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString
                        If voc.Description.EndsWith("-") Then
                            a = Replace(voc.Description, "-", "") 
                            voc.Description = a
                        End If

                    End If
                    stringVoice = voc.Description
                    voices.Add(voc)
```

but in this case I've never had an error.

Can anyone help me to fix my code?

Comment: So, if I read this right, your first example gets an error and the 2nd example works.  The first example, your length check is on voc.Description but then you take the substring of grid(r,3).Text which may be shorter than voc.Description

Comment: grid(r,3) is where I have the description. Initially I check if the cell contains more than 255 characters and then I put grid(r,3) into voc.Description. In the first example I've already got  the description inside voc.Description

Comment: Have you step through the code and look at the value of each variable?

Comment: Problem solved. Instead of `voc.Description = grid(r, 3).Text.ToString.Substring(0, 252) + "..."'` I've written `voc.Description = voc.Description.ToString.Substring(0, 252) + "..."`. Now it works. Thanks to all